# Derive another table with data from row values of another table mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, key-value

[image]

How can the above table be transformed to give the result below (php mysql)?

Desired Output

```
| perf_o | names      | gender | age |
-------------------------------------- 
| 28     |  John Doe  |  male  | 38  |
| 26     |  mary jane | female | 20  |
```

Comment: Have you bothered trying to do this yourself? This should be one of the first things you pickup when learning php

Comment: Using mysql and some `JOIN`s you should be able to do it. No need for php. Once you have some SQL that doesn't work please come back here and we'll be very glad to help you!

Comment: I also fail to understand why you've made the DB this way.. Surely it'd be more logical to simply add more fields to said table...

Comment: @Option Am able to get data from the table and is ok, the only thing am missing is how to use the data to form another table thats more simpler as you're suggesting. However, the table am working on contains thousands of this kind of information that someone else did.

Comment: @Option in reality this is a good approach as long as `perf_o` is a unique identifier. Let's say that after a year of using this you want to add an email field. With your method they'd have to create a new column for the table, with this method all they have to do is insert a `5 , mary jane, email, a@a.a, 26` and boom! You have it. It allows for more flexibility. Another approach would be to store the data inside JSON objects or XML. But then it becomes a mix between NoSQL databases and relational ones and for some, it is harder to manage/understand.

Comment: @Antoniu, Perhaps it's a personal preference... But, this way seems so dragged out it's just causing further code further down the line... Makes more sense to just have further fields

Answer (score 1):

This table design is a somewhat goofy key/value setup. It's "somewhat goofy" because those setup usually have a master and a detail table, but here the master table is [denormalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) into the detail table. There doesn't seem to be a performance reason for the [denormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization).

So, you need to use a subquery to do this perfectly. The subquery generates the master table.

```
                SELECT DISTINCT names, perf_o FROM tbl
```

It gives one row for each person in your input table. (This assumes that each person has a distinct value of `perf_o`; I guess that's true, but you did not say so.)

Then you join that twice to your detail table, once for each value of `info`.

```
SELECT master.perf_o, master.names,
       gender.d_prov AS gender,
       age.d_prov AS age
  FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT names, perf_o FROM tbl
       ) master
  LEFT JOIN tbl gender ON gender.perf_o = master.perf_o AND info = 'gender'
  LEFT JOIN tbl age    ON age.perf_o    = master.perf_o AND info = 'age'
```

Each of the `LEFT JOIN` operations picks up one of your chosen keys, and associates it with the `master` table.

This seems complex, but it will do something reasonable for cases where no age or no gender is recorded for the person.

You have presented a problem that's trickier than usual for somebody just starting out with SQL. Please *please* don't just cut and paste my answer; instead try to understand it.

Comment: hi @O. Jones, thank you for the reply and the caution too. Supposing the `info` has many values that are/was added that I left out as @Antoniu Livadariu had pointed out(In this case, each person has 12 different `info` entries). Do I have to like mention all the values of each as your solution proposes? I'll be careful not to copy paste but interested in understanding the whole concept. Than you once again.

Comment: Where the number of distinct values of `info` is large or the values are unknown ahead of time, the problem you're solving is called *pivoting* the table. Pivoting is a notorious pain in the neck in MySQL.   My suggestion: don't try to solve the general case in SQL. Instead enumerate the different values of `info`. It makes a verbose query, but you'll finish it sooner. (Or write a php program to do it.)

Comment: thank you for the info, given the number of tables am dealing with, I will try write php code to help ease the work, in the meantime, I will test your proposed solution directly.